# Can I have the newest version of perl together with olde

Tags: perl

I have on UNIX SunOS 5.9 Generic_122300-61 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-V240 perl v5.6.1, but I want to install the newest version.

Can I install the newest version and have it together with oldest but on different directories?

But my questions is :

now I have perl home on /bin/perl.

The newest perl version will be on different home directory? And also cpan and modules, are they going to be installed?

Comment: Does [perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/) exist for your platform?

Comment: http://weblog.bulknews.net/post/58079418600/plenv-alternative-for-perlbrew

Comment: Another one is [plenv](https://github.com/tokuhirom/plenv).

Comment: Haha, @mpapec, I was going for the same thing. :)

Comment: If you install multiple versions of the Perl interpreter, you can share a lib directory between them but only for pure Perl modules.  Modules that include a compiled C component will generally be built for a specific version of Perl and loading them with a different version may trigger a segfault.  But the pure-Perl ones are fine.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are on Solaris, don't mess with the Perl that comes with the operating system. It's used by the OS itself, and if you change it things can get weird.

That said, you can absolutely install other Perl versions in parallel with it. If you're compiling manually, all you need to do is to give the flag `-Dprefix=/some/nice/directory` to the Configure script. Once it's compiled and installed, you only need to put /some/nice/directory/bin earlier in your PATH than /usr/bin.

If you want a system-wide installation of a newer Perl, I'd suggest picking the latest version (currently 5.20.0, but 5.20.1 is at RC2 so it should be out soon) and installing it in /usr/local. If you want a newer Perl for your own personal use, I'd strongly suggest making sure you have enough of an environment that Perl can be compiled, and then install and use perlbrew (http://perlbrew.pl/).